# how to line break on placholder of text area

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am looking to line break on placeholder of textarea on reactjs

So far I have tried to use `\n`, `<br>`, `nl2br`, `\\n` and none of them worked

```
<Input type="textarea" name="txtarea"  placeholder="Line1  \n Line2" />
```

The current output im getting all in the same line as `Line1  \n Line2`

My goal is to have them out on a separate line as

```
Line1 
Line2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Newlines do not work in the placeholder attribute of `<input>` elements, but they work for the `<textarea>` element.

However, using `<input type="textarea">` is not valid markup and will be replaced by the browser to an `<input type="text">`.

If you want multi-line input, use a `<textarea>` instead.

For the newline, use the `&#13;` and `&#10;` HTML entities in your placeholder, which are the `line feed` and the `new line` characters:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="line&#13;&#10;line2">
<textarea placeholder="line1&#13;&#10;line2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari Technology Preview 113

Comment: nothing less than a genius

Comment: Does not work in Safari 14.1.2

Answer (score 1):

You have to put that `&#10;` insted `\n` inside the placeholder