# Multiline placeholder in textarea for safari and firefox

Tags: reactjs, sharetribe

I'm trying to add a placeholder to a textarea in the forms in my reactjs project. The placeholder is multiline and looks like this

```
      <textarea
        {...this.props}
        ref={textarea => {
          this.textarea = textarea;
        }}
        placeholder={'Address Line1\nAddress Line\nCity State, Zip\nCountry'}
      />
```

on chrome, the text holder is rendered as [multiline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEgiH.png) properly. on firefox it's just a [single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRybU.png) even if the text is there and on safari, the placeholder text is rendered as [one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUJkm.png) only

i've been going through different stackoverflow posts

- [how to line break on placholder of text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54618219/how-to-line-break-on-placholder-of-text-area)
- [How to add multi line place holder text in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437942/how-to-add-multi-line-place-holder-text-in-textarea)
- [Can you have multiline HTML5 placeholder text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea)

and from what i could tell, while this wasn't allowed before, it's part of the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-placeholder) now and it should work.

Has anyone gotten this to work on different browsers?

UPDATE (Nov 16): I added a "rows" attribute to the placeholder and the lines were displayed. still didn't work for safari